# Cannot install Cocoapods into app when typing "pod install" (ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, permission-denied, osx-yosemite

I am using OSX Yoemite and I have visited almost all questions about this on StackOverflow and none of the answers worked... I am currently trying to use the command "pod install" and I am getting this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/xcodeproj-0.16.1 (Errno::EACCES)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `write_gem_make_out'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `block in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `find'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/bin/pod:32:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

And it also says: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed my error. All I had to do was type $ brew install postgresql in terminal.

Comment: were you using a cocoa pods library that's dependent on PostgreSQL ?

Comment: I'm not sure... but I found that answer on stackoverflow but can't track back to where I  found it. I really wish to give my bounty to him...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (Worked for me with OSX 10.10)

1. Open Xcode 6
2. Open Preferences
3. Click the Locations tab
4. **Change the Command Line Tools version to Xcode 6.0**
5. Uninstall cocoapods

   $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
6. Install xcodeproj

   $ sudo gem install xcodeproj
7. Install cocoapods

   $ sudo gem install cocoapods

Run `pod --version` to verify

Comment: I keep getting this when I do $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the DevTools installed, try: xcode-select --install

Comment: Is CocoaPods compatible with Yosemite? Are there indications of it working elsewhere? Perhaps 10.10 upgraded to a version of Ruby that is not compatible with CocoaPods.

Comment: Yes cocoapods is compatible with Yosemite. stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/… but that solution is giving me the error that I added into my question. @SevenBits

Answer (score 2):

```
 rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p247 --with-gcc=clang --verify-downloads 1
 gem install xcodeproj
 gem install cocoapods
```

Try these which might be helpful

Comment: I've already tried that and tried tried it again just now. Still the Same error...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know I'm late to the party here, but here's some info for future generations in case they hit the same issue as me.

The problem I hit was due to my project directory being created by another user (and so I didn't have permission to do mkdir).  Updating permissions (or in my case, re-creating the project directory using my user account) fixed the issue.

Hope this helps! :)